# oracle job to count active number of connections in Database

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle DB ,  now as i am monitoring the performance of oracle DB which is connected to my java application , so rite now i have to monitor the count of active connections in DB at regular intervals lets say after every 30 minutes  below is the query which return me the count of active users along with there name and count

```
select osuser, count(osuser) as active_conn_count 
from v$session 
group by osuser 
order by active_conn_count desc
```

now please  advise how can i make an job in oracle DB itself that will get triggered at every 30 minutes , and capture the  above query result that is the count of active connections as per the user and also Oracle DB memory usage at that time

Comment: These are two very different questions. What do you need help with - how to query the database to get DB memory usage, or how to use `dbms_scheduler` to run the job every 30 minutes? It would be best if you would DELETE this post, and create two instead, asking each question separately. For example, I can help with the first one; I haven't used the scheduler, so I can't help with the second.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove this question and ask it as two separate questions (see my Comment under your question). You are asking two questions: 1. How to get memory usage; 2. How to schedule the job. Answering only the first question here.

To get memory usage you could use something like this (with the output from my database at this moment):

```
select case grouping_id(nm) when 1 then 'total' else nm end as nm, 
       round(sum(val/1024/1024)) mb
from (
       select 'sga' nm, sum(value) val
         from v$sga
       union all
       select 'pga', sum(value)
       from v$sysstat
       where name = 'session pga memory'
)
group by rollup(nm)
;

NM      MB
----- ----
pga     49
sga   4896
total 4945
```